# Cannot install anything! Unmet dependencies. Libre Office

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, libreoffice, dependencies

Please help, I've searched around loads and can't seem to find a solution that works.

I recently removed libre office and installed open office. After trying to reinstall libreoffice. I now can't install anything with `apt-get`

Forgive me but I'm new and I can't seem to figure out how to post big blocks of code. I get the following output when clicking "repair" in ubuntu software centre. Running Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...  (Reading database ...
5% (Reading database ... 10% (Reading database ... 15% (Reading
database ... 20% (Reading database ... 25% (Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35% (Reading database ... 40% (Reading database
... 45% (Reading database ... 50% (Reading database ... 55% (Reading
database ... 60% (Reading database ... 65% (Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75% (Reading database ... 80% (Reading database
... 85% (Reading database ... 90% (Reading database ... 95% (Reading
database ... 100% (Reading database ... 584380 files and directories
currently installed.) Removing ure-dbg (4.4.2~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1)
... Removing uno-libs3-dbg (4.4.2~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1) ... (Reading
database ...  (Reading database ... 5% (Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15% (Reading database ... 20% (Reading database
... 25% (Reading database ... 30% (Reading database ... 35% (Reading
database ... 40% (Reading database ... 45% (Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55% (Reading database ... 60% (Reading database
... 65% (Reading database ... 70% (Reading database ... 75% (Reading
database ... 80% (Reading database ... 85% (Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95% (Reading database ... 100% (Reading database
... 584319 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to
unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb ... Unpacking
libreoffice-common (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2) ... dpkg: error processing
archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb
(--unpack):  trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in
package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775 rmdir: failed to remove
/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/: No such file or directory rmdir:
failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/: No such file or
directory rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/program/: No
such file or directory rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice:
No such file or directory rmdir: failed to remove
/var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory Processing triggers
for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ... Unknown media type in type
'all/all' Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles' Unknown media type
in type 'uri/mms' Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst' Unknown media
type in type 'uri/mmsu' Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm' Unknown
media type in type 'uri/rtspt' Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ... Processing
triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ... Processing triggers for
gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ... Processing triggers for
desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding
/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... Processing triggers for
hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ... Processing triggers for
gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ... Errors were encountered while
processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb
Error in function:  dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
libreoffice-l10n-ml:  libreoffice-l10n-ml depends on
libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common is not
installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-ml (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-mn:  libreoffice-l10n-mn
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-mn (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-mk:  libreoffice-l10n-mk
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-mk (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-mr:  libreoffice-l10n-mr
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-mr (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-gl:  libreoffice-l10n-gl
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-gl (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-gd:  libreoffice-l10n-gd
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-gd (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-ga:  libreoffice-l10n-ga
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-ga (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-gu:  libreoffice-l10n-gu
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-gu (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-kmr-latn:
libreoffice-l10n-kmr-latn depends on libreoffice-common; however:
Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-kmr-latn
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-ss:
libreoffice-l10n-ss depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package
libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-ss (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-sr:  libreoffice-l10n-sr
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-sr (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-sv:  libreoffice-l10n-sv
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-sv (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-st:  libreoffice-l10n-st
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-st (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-sk:  libreoffice-l10n-sk
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-sk (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-si:  libreoffice-l10n-si
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-si (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-sl:  libreoffice-l10n-sl
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-sl (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-pt-br:
libreoffice-l10n-pt-br depends on libreoffice-common; however:
Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-pt-br (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-nr:  libreoffice-l10n-nr
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-nr (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-ne:  libreoffice-l10n-ne
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-ne (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-nb:  libreoffice-l10n-nb
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-nb (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-nl:  libreoffice-l10n-nl
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-nl (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-nn:  libreoffice-l10n-nn
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-nn (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-zu:  libreoffice-l10n-zu
depends on libreoffice-common; however:   Package libreoffice-common
is not installed.
```

Comment: It appears you can not have openoffice and libreoffice installed at the same time. Use one or the other. If you wish to return to libre, completely remove open.  Read the error message "dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775 "

Answer (score 1):

BACK UP IMPORTANT FILES FIRST

Type the following in terminal to remove libreoffice and openoffice:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* openoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then install one or the other, this seems to be the only way.

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

If it is not found

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

Comment: Thanks! I can now install things. However, I'm now getting error after installing libreoffice in the way you suggest:

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Did you - sudo apt-get update

Comment: Yeah... getting 

libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed plus a load of other dependencies...

Comment: OK as a quick fix try software center, it will auto resolve

Comment: Tried that... get an error when trying to install "libreoffice" that says "Package dependencies cannot be resolved". Details show:libreoffice: Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2) but 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

Comment: sudo apt-get install  libreoffice-core

Comment: libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:4.2.7) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ure (>= 4.2~) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: uno-libs3 (>= 4.2.0~rc1) but it is not going to be installed

I actually did apt-get libreoffice-common and it installed without issue but this still throws an error. Apparently I still have "held broken packages"

Comment: Run the following 4 commands one at a time, should fix "held broken packages"   sudo apt-get install -f     sudo dpkg --configure -a     sudo apt-get clean   sudo apt-get update    - then try a software center  install again

Comment: Output for the above commands was "0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 23 not to upgrade. I did apt-get upgrade which changed the 23 to 0 but still getting the same error as above in software centre...

Comment: Are you familiar with synaptic ?   sudo apt-get install synaptic   Install this, open it from the dash, choose "custom filters" from the bottom left, now choose "broken" from above, this will list any broken packages on your PC, uninstall them, reinstall any that are not "libreoffice" and then install libreoffice.  You can do all this from synaptic

Comment: I'm afraid that nothing is listed under the broken packages in synaptic...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had to go back to work, do you still need help with this ? If so please run-  sudo apt-get install  libreoffice  -and post the exact error, if its to long for long add it to the question.

Comment: Hi Mark, no problem. Thank you so far for all your help. The problem is at one of my work computers which I don't have access to until Monday. I ended up re-installing openoffice which works fine and I'm not having any problems doing apt-get install anymore. I assume it's to do with the conflict between libre and open office.

Comment: Ok, if you are happy with open then use that, but feel free to post here if you would liked to try fix it again.